# Which settings to use in hook_field_formatter_view?

Tags: 7, entities

Looking at the page of [`hook_field_formatter_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7), the explanation for `$display` is:

> The display settings to use, **as found in the 'display' entry of instance definitions**. The array notably contains the following keys and values;

But I just found out that the `$display` variable does not hold accurate information.

This is what's inside my `$instance` (correct settings)
[image: instance settings]

This is what's inside my `$display` (default values for settings)
[image]

I could overwrite `$display` from the `$instance` settings, but I can't figure out in which variable the current view mode is stored, so that I can grab the settings for the correct view mode.

As a little background info, this is a custom field with a custom formatter. Has anyone had similar issues with a custom field/formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't really a problem. This was because the page was a Panels page, and the field was added into the panel page with its own formatter settings.

Solved by setting the correct field formatter settings on the panel page.

It's one of d'ohs days.